# Is there any way in android to reduce boot time from xml parshing?

Tags: android

In my android application i have 3 tabs. when we click any tab it will display  the list of  data coming from xml parshing. when we move from one tab to another tab it will take 3-5 mins to load the data.so   it creates a confusion that data is  changing or not  . so how can i increase the performance of data loading from xml parshing .

Comment: please give more details. Where does the xml come from? Assets or web? What parser are you using? Have you used traceview to see which parts of your code are slow?

Comment: yes, you should change your device to the one with quad-core processor ...

Comment: Data coming from web.XML dom parsher used.i am using segment controller , when i move from one tab to other the data of previous tab is visible upto  3-4 mins and then appropriate data is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that data in local

So first time it will Load from xml and store in local

and second time it will display from that local data.

So ti will not take much time.

you can also add refresh button.